# Query between dates stored as text

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table (not build by me) containing date column (regDate - e.g. 18/10/2016) as text and columns with only the year and mumeric month.
My problem is to run a query viewing data between the 8th month of 2016 and the 10th month of the 2017.
How do I convert this date format(s) to view the results ?

Comment: Please post some code what you have tried before

Comment: hint : `Cast(regDate as datetime)` and `DATEPART(MM, Cast(regDate as datetime))`

Answer (score 0):

Convert your to Datetime in SQL Server.  Assuming you have date in this format `18/10/2016`.

```
select CONVERT(date, '18/10/2016', 103)
```

You can convert your date in `where` clause then use `between` query.

Comment: the query is between MM/YYYY string to date conversion

Answer (score 0):

I would use `datefromparts()`:

```
where convert(date, regdate, 103) >= datefromparts(2016, 8, 1) and
      convert(date, regdate, 103) < dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(2017, 10, 1))
```

As a word of clarification:  You have a *text* column that happens to represent a date.  You do not have a *date* column.

I would strongly recommend that you fix the column type in the table:

```
update t
    set regdate = convert(date, regdate, 103) ;  -- this will format using the default date format

alter t alter column regdate date;
```

Comment: 'datefromparts' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: you' re right I don't have a date column and isn't possible to fix or add a new date column in the table

Comment: @AndyL. . . . `datefromparts()` has been part of SQL Server since 2012:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      11.0.2100.60